# How do I store a query into a variable so that I can use it twice?

Tags: mysql, variables, optimization, select

I have the following query where I select all of the ids from a table to compare to to filter some ids as being 'backblaze sales orders'. I've noticed that after each check to the report, it increases the time it takes by 10 seconds. How can I select that table into a variable that I can compare things to to be more efficient so that the table isn't queried over and over?

So far I've used the temp_table from paul's answer but it gives me an error saying "can't reopen temptable."

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE if not exists TempTable (id varchar(36)); 
INSERT INTO TempTable (id)
SELECT
   id
FROM 
   reporting.backblaze_sales_orders;
SELECT
  2011 as year,
  so.technical_address_country,
  so.technical_address_state,
  /* ALL JOBs */
  COUNT(so.id) as all_sales,
  COUNT(mf.id) as all_jobs,
  SUM(so.total_value) as all_value,
    SUM(IF(so.check_if_new_customer=1,1,0)) as sales_order_new,
  SUM(IF(so.check_if_new_customer = 1,so.total_value,0)) as total_value_new,
    SUM(IF(so.check_if_new_customer=1 AND mf.id IS NOT NULL,1,0)) as jobs_new,
    SUM(IF(so.check_if_new_customer=0,1,0)) as sales_order_existing,
  SUM(IF(so.check_if_new_customer = 0,so.total_value,0)) as total_value_existing,
    SUM(IF(so.check_if_new_customer=0 AND mf.id IS NOT NULL,1,0)) as jobs_existing,
      /* ALL JOBs */
  COUNT(so.id) as all_sales_back_blaze,
  COUNT(mf.id) as all_jobs_back_blaze,
  SUM(so.total_value) as all_value,
    SUM(IF(so.check_if_new_customer=1 AND so.id not in (SELECT id from TempTable) ,1,0)) as sales_order_new_back_blaze,
  SUM(IF(so.check_if_new_customer = 1 AND so.id not in (SELECT id from TempTable),so.total_value,0)) as total_value_new_back_blaze,
    SUM(IF(so.check_if_new_customer=1 AND  mf.id IS NOT NULL AND so.id not in (SELECT id from TempTable),1,0)) as jobs_new_back_blaze,
    SUM(IF(so.check_if_new_customer=0 AND so.id not in (SELECT id from TempTable),1,0)) as sales_order_existing_back_blaze,
  SUM(IF(so.check_if_new_customer = 0 AND so.id not in (SELECT id from TempTable),so.total_value,0)) as total_value_existing_back_blaze,
    SUM(IF(so.check_if_new_customer=0 AND mf.id IS NOT NULL AND so.id not in (SELECT id from TempTable),1,0)) as jobs_existing_back_blaze
FROM 
  sugarcrm2.so_order so 
LEFT JOIN 
  sugarcrm2.mf_job mf on so.id = mf.sales_order_id 
WHERE 
  so.date_entered > "2010-10-30" AND so.date_entered >"2011-10-30" AND
    so.technical_address_country IS NOT NULL AND  
  so.technical_address_state IS NOT NULL AND 
  so.deleted = 0 AND 
  so.has_been_promoted = 1 
GROUP BY 
    YEAR(so.date_entered),
  so.technical_address_country, 
  so.technical_address_state
ORDER BY 
  so.technical_address_country, so.technical_address_state
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to simply join to that table and test if the joined table's id is null or not.

Answer (score 2):

Didn't read through all your code, but sounds like you need a temporary table.  These can be used like this:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TempTable (id int, otherValue varchar(100)); 

INSERT INTO TempTable (id, otherValue)
SELECT
   id,
   someOtherValue
FROM ....
```

Then use this table instead of your query.

Comment: So I've changed my query to try to use the temptable as you suggested but it tells me 'temptable' already exists, so I changed it to 'temptable1' and it gives me the same error. It's at the top of my code in my edited example.

Comment: Your answer works for one of the subqueries but it complains that I can't use the temptable again in the query.

Answer (score 1):

Use a cursor:
http://www.brainbell.com/tutorials/MySQL/Working_With_Cursors.htm

```
DECLARE ordernumbers CURSOR
   FOR
   SELECT ordernum FROM orders;
```

This is just a hint!
I hope someone can use it to give a full answer.

Comment: So, how do I take this select, and make it into something usable by the query above? When I do the above query with SET @var := (SELECT id from reporting.table) it complains that my subquery returns more than one row.

Comment: I'm looking to select all the ids in a table.

Comment: This is useful but can this only be used in procedures?

Comment: yeah those cursors can only be used in stored procedures or functions.
you need to declare them at the beginning of the procedure
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/cursors.html

Comment: Hmm i think you should go with Paul´s solution.

Comment: Ah, I haven't used stored procedures before, at least not made my own, I've called a few.

Comment: I already have a full table though, do I still need a temp table?

Comment: Thanks a bunch though, I think Paul's may be more my speed.

Comment: Have you used temptables like in paul's example before?